# Combine future contracts into time series

Tags: time-series, programming, futures, backtesting

I have future contracts from 10 years back that are combined in one file. There is a gap in the data every month due to rolling of the contracts. How do I remove this gap ad get a smooth time series that I can perform backtesting on.

Comment: There are a few ways how synthetic continuous series are constructed from raw data of futures prices. Think of how you would actually trade, which contract you would buy/sell at which time, and that will determine how you construct or alter your series.

Comment: I will use moving averege strategies.

Comment: By the way, the gaps your are seeing in your data are (most likely) very real, while a continuous line you would like to have would be largely illusionary.

Comment: The gaps are not real they are due to contracts rolling. Do you have a method to solve it?

Comment: The synthetic continuous series is nontradable, so in this sense it is not real. The actual contracts that are tradable but they produce the gaps you are seeing.

Comment: The method(s) to solve it are found by searching for 'continuous futures contracts".